# Display REST API content in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: c#, azure-devops, postman

Im new to Azure and Postman.

Is there a way to display the content of a (GET)Rest API in Azure DevOPS.
The content should be displayed inside the "Run Cake script" in the Pipeline.

Right now i have this:

```
Task("Deploy")
    .IsDependentOn("Pack")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        //Code to print the content of the API packages.
    });
```

How do i proceed?
Once again, im new to this so i might be missing a lot of information that you need in order to help me. In that case, let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with Cake script, there are 2 ways to do authentication for Azure DevOps API.

1. Private PAT
2. Environment Variable: System.AccessToken

if you want to call Azure DevOps API in your pipeline, you can conside use System.AccessToken.

Here is Powershell Script for your reference, the field of Authorization is different.

```
function Http-Request {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string] $SystemToken
    )
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SystemToken)) {
        $pat = 'YOUR_PAT'
        $username = 'YOUR_USERNAME'
        $auth = '{0}:{1}' -f $username, $pat
        $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($auth)
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
        $auth = 'Basic ' + $encoded
    } else {
        $auth = 'Bearer ' + $SystemToken
    }
    $headers = @{
      'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
      'Authorization' = $auth
    }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Http Request:'$Url
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -Headers $headers
    Write-Host ($reponse | Format-List | Out-String)
    return $response
}
```